# How to get Job Title and Telephone Number from the UserInfo Endpoint

Tags: php, docusignapi

The `UserInfo` endpoint returns partial information about the logged in user.
`Job Title`, `Telephone Number` and `Address` are missing. Although it is possible to enter these details on the "My Profile" page.

I set the `Job Title`, `Telephone Number` and `Address` under "My Profile" page, however the `UserInfo` endpoint returns a fixed set of fields.

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/user-info-endpoints
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/userinfo

I expect the endpoint to return `Job Title`, `Telephone Number` and `Address` fields.

Comment: Can you add some code of what you are doing to your question

Answer (score 3):

you will need to call a different API for this information.
This API - `GET /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}`
the userID is the GUID you can find in the UserInfo or you can also find it in the web application.
The return object includes all information DocuSign has for this user and you can find it [`here`](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Users/Users/get)